# Nimbus not re-starting Storm supervisor

Tags: apache-storm

We have multi-machine storm cluster. Over storm UI we can see total number of supervisor equal to total number of machine. I thought, nimbus should restart supervisor of another machine or same machine when it die within same cluster. Please advise what is missing ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK, Nimbus doesn't kill or restart Supervisor.

Nimbus finds list of live Supervisors from Zookeeper using ephemeral node when Nimbus needs to ask some Supervisors to do the job.

That's all. Nimbus doesn't take care of Supervisors directly.